# Mediawiki file link to URL is not updated

Tags: hyperlink, format, mediawiki

I have a mediawiki page with a file link on this format:

```
[[File:Workflow.png|link=<URL goes here>]]
```

It does work but I thought that the image would be always up to date with the server. Today I changed the image but it was not updated on the Wiki. Clicking on the image goes to it's updated version.

Any idea? Is this the wrong way of achieving that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe a browser caching issue? clear your browser cache and try again...

Comment: Looks like this is not the correct format for what I need. That format just shows a file which links to the other image. I thought it would create a link that updates it self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you are wanting to do is embed an external image. In order to do that, please set your `$wgAllowExternalImages` parameter in LocalSettings.php to `true`.
Then, in your article, just add the URL of your image where you want it to appear.

However, please notice that thumbnailing of external images need assistance of [robothumb](http://www.robothumb.com/). The syntax is the following one:

```
http://www.robothumb.com/src/[url]@[size](.jpg)
```

More information [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aImages).

Comment: It doesn't work on my case, shows an icon that is in process but never is done. I guess is due to the fact that the URL is in the company's intranet. Gave you thumbs up for the right answer, just doesn't work on my particular case.

Comment: @javydreamercsw I'm really sure it didn't work due to the fact that the URL is in the company's intranet. You could try with any other image in the internet, but I guess that won't work for what you want.  Thanks for the thumbs up!